# SQL Query - Orders Not Shipped With Next Expected Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with a query. I need to be able to show outstanding orders (not shipped).

An order item can have a date when the customer is expecting the item by. This can be NULL.

I have the following tables

**SalesOrder**

```
SalesOrderId (PK)
```

**SalesOrderItem**

```
SalesOrderItem (PK)  
SalesOrderId (FK)
Qty  
Description  
DateExpected (DateTime | Nullable)
```

**Shipment**

```
ShipmentId (PK)
```

**ShipmentItem**

```
ShipmentItemId (PK)  
ShipmentId (FK)  
SalesOrderItemId (FK)  
Qty
```

A sales order item can have many shipment items relating to it (for split shipping).

I need a list of outstanding orders with the next expected date for each. I am struggling because I am not sure of the most economic way of doing this.

I could select all of the orders that have calculated ShippedQty < calculated OrderedQty and then join that to the order items again to get `MIN(DateExpected)` but I think that would be quite cumbersome with a large dataset.

The columns I need from the query would be:

**Query Result**

```
SalesOrderId  
NextDateExpected (Date or NULL)
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data along with the expected results

Comment: Can you please tell me the best way to add sample data? Thank you

Comment: Ideally script out the tables as create table statements, include only the columns necessary for your problem and add sample data as insert into ... values(), this will make it easy for someone to reproduce your results and offer a solution.

Comment: I think you missed the SalesOrderId in SalesOrderItem

Comment: You're right, Turo. I have now added it. Unfortunately I have never figured out SQL Fiddle or how to post table structures using the StackOverflow editor. I will have to go back to the drawing board. Thank you anyway

Comment: Do NOT prematurely optimize. First goal is to get a query that works correctly. And it is past time to learn how to post using fiddle or just with a script - it just is **not that difficult**. At a minimum you should post DDL in the question along with a small sample set of data. You seem to have an idea for a query - what is stopping you from writing that and testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way with CTE and subselect could be

```
WITH cte as
(select SalesOrderID , Min(DateExpected) DateExpected 
    from SalesOrderItem o group by SalesOrderId, SalesOrderItem
    having sum(Qty) <> (select COALESCE(sum(qty),0) from ShipmentItem s where s.SalesOrderItem = o.SalesOrderItem) )

select SalesOrderId, Min(DateExpected) DateExpected from cte
group by SalesOrderId
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8969c2182375b59bdbc61f66f880a6d)

Feel free to use and amend the fiddle to improve your question.

But Mark B has a point int saying a boolen flag for finished SalesOrders
would be good, but maybe such a query could help marking SalesOrders as finished periodicly...

Comment: This was the fastest solution. Many thanks, Turo.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most economic way of doing this would be to add a status field to the SalesOrder (and possibly the SalesOrderItem) table. You could then eliminate most of the orders from the query before having to calculate the shipped quantity. This will get to be a bigger benefit when the data grows over time. The status could be a boolean flag to mark complete or fully shipped orders.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for your comment. I was always told to avoid something like this as you would need to add a lot of checks when adding items, removing, changing qty etc. There are so many more opportunities for errors to occur.

Comment: Hi steve_c123 you need to weigh up the pros and cons for yourself but I would say that the saving in finding open orders quickly (particularly once the database has grown over time) would outweigh the small inconvinience of adding a flag setting function that checks that the specific order has been satisfied and sets the flag appropriately

Comment: I think you're probably right, Mark. Having a look at the performance benefits, it's worth spending the extra time coding.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to express the logic that you want:

```
select SalesOrderId,
       min(case when soi.qty > si.qty then soi.dateExpected end) as min_expected_date
from salesOrder so left join
     salesOrderItem soi
     on soi.SalesOrderId = soi.SalesOrderId left join
     (select si.SalesOrderItemId, sum(qty) as shipped_qty
      from ShipmentItem si
      group by si.SalesOrderItemId,
     ) si
     on si.SalesOrderItemId = soi.SalesOrderItemId
group by so.SalesOrderId;
```

I would work on getting the logic right -- perhaps testing on sample data to be sure it is correct.  Then, if performance is problem, you can work on optimizations.